Is the reduced of complete intersection variety still complete intersection?
Let $V=Proj(\mathbb{k}[x_0,...,x_n]/I)$ be a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $I$ is generated by $n-dim(V)$ homegenous elements. Is that true that for $V_{red}=Proj(\mathbb{k}[x_0,...,x_n]/\sqrt{I})$, $\sqrt{I}$ is generated by $n-dim(V)$ elements.
How about the converse?

No. Try three general points in the plane.

I don’t understand the question. Which implication do you want to prove or disprove?

Both implications are false.
The easy one: if $I$ is generated by a regular sequence, then $I^2$ will usually not be. For instance $I=(x,y)$ and $I^2=(x^2,xy,y^2)$ in $k[x,y]$.
The other one: take $k[x,y,z]$ and consider $I=(xy+xz+yz,xyz)$. You can see by hand that the solution set in the projective plane is 3 points: $[1:0:0]$, $[0:1:0]$, $[0:0:1]$, so this is generated by a regular sequence. But it's not a radical ideal, and in fact the radical is $(xy,yz,xz)$, which is not generated by a regular sequence.
As an aside: Eisenbud and Evans https://eudml.org/doc/142190 showed that for every algebraic subset of projective $n$-space, there is a homogeneous ideal generated by at most $n$ elements whose radical is the radical ideal of that set. So you can produce many counterexamples to the second implication by taking any collection of points in $P^n$ whose radical ideal is not generated by a regular sequence (though getting the explicit ideals may be a challenge).
